# Canvas 3d changing the direction of canvas axis

Tags: html, canvas, graph, html5-canvas

I am using canvas 3d to draw a 3D graph.But by default origin of Coordinates is at top left.For which i used translate and bring it to the center of canvas as follows.

```
canvasElement.getContext('2d').translate(constants.canvasWidth/2,   constants.canvasHeight/2);
```

where canvasWidth and canvasHeight are already defined.
But now i have another problem with the direction of axis.Now positive y axis is facing down and -ve y-axis facing up.How can make it proper so that +ve y-axis faces up and -ve y-axis faces down?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of offsetting the centre calculate the y position.
Subtract the y value from the height of the canvas/2.

```
x1 = canvasHeight/2 + x;
y1 = canvasHeight/2 - y;
```

Comment: I have not understood what you have mentioned here.Should i use this in translate or any function? How to use it?

Comment: Use this to translate all co-ordinates. You may also want a scaling factor. So you can fit any size graph onto the canvas. If you want 3D graphs you'll probably want to use Transformation Matrices.